# Rational power in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was going through Batch RSA and in one such case they have used\

t = $\ m^x$ mod n where x is of the form 1/e where e is an integer.

what does t mean and will it be an integer ?

Eg if m = 10, e = 2 and n = 100 then will t = $\sqrt10$ mod 100 or something else

Please refer the figure. I'm asking about something like $\ V ^ (1/E) $

[image]

Comment: $2$ is not invertible modulo $100,$ so that's not a good example. What they mean by $1/e$ is some integer $d$ such that $de\equiv1\pmod{n}.$

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE! Have a look into my answer made today: [What do some cryptographic terminology mean?(e.g. public params, security params)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977392/what-do-some-cryptographic-terminology-meane-g-public-params-security-params/2977408#2977408)

In view of the RSA (Rivest, Shamir, Adlement) cryptosystem, each user chooses two large primes $p$ and $q$. Then she (beloved Alice) computes $n=p⋅q$ and $ϕ(n)=(p−1)(q−1)$. Afterwards she chooses an integer $e$ in the range $1<e<ϕ(n)$, usually a prime, such that $e$ is invertible modulo $ϕ(n)$. Then she computes $d=e^1$ in Zϕ(n). Then $(n,e)$ is the public key and $d$ is the private key.
In your context, $x$ equals $d$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was going through Batch RSA